# how to use original dataset to get the logistic regression?

Tags: probability, regression-analysis, logistic-regression

This from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression

[image]

I understand P(X=2)=0.26 is the predicted probability when hours is 2 after the logistic regression. I want to know how do we use original data points to use least square method to produce the logistic regression equation?

Comment: @joriki  yes,The student who studied for 22 hours failed.I want to know how do we use original dataset to use least square method to produce the logistic regression equation?

Comment: @joriki Sorry for the confusing description, I have changed the question

Comment: OK, I've deleted my comments. Note that the Wikipedia article you linked to has a section [Model fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Model_fitting) that deals with your question.

Comment: Note that logistic regression does _not_ use least squares for model fit.

Comment: @Roland: Hmm -- that Wikipedia section says it does, but I don't have a clue myself.